# File Not found exception on different Machine

Tags: java, file, ubuntu

i am trying to access file from opt/app/db/vat/form_data_30.xls.
It works fine on my machine but shows exception on other machine on which application is installed.
 Here is code

```
String fileName="opt/app/db/vat/form_dvat_30.xls";
File selectedFile=new File(fileName);
```

Physically .xls file exist inside opt/app/db/vat directory.And users have all permission of read write as well.
Mine runnable jar app.jar is stored at /opt/app/app.jar

Comment: you use file separator.

Comment: Yes i already mention that file exist physically on target computer(Also ubntu).

Comment: and is the other machine also linux?

Comment: @AnoopLL yes tother machine is also linux.

Comment: `opt/app/db/vat/form_dvat_30.xls` is a relative path, is the program executing at the location above the `opt` directory?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Mine runnable jar app.jar is stored at /opt/app/app.jar and accessing file from opt/app/db/vat/form_dvat_30.xls

Comment: try `/opt/` instead of `opt/`

Answer (score 1):

If you use `String fileName="opt/app/db/vat/form_dvat_30.xls";` then its relative to the execution folder.

For example if the programe is executed from `/home/user/` then the file should be in `/home/user/opt/app/db/vat/form_dvat_30.xls`

If you want to access `/opt/app/db/vat/form_dvat_30.xls` then use `String fileName="/opt/app/db/vat/form_dvat_30.xls";`